# Python 3: "Local Variable referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x

already looked at other answers and can't seem to fix this.

Here's my full code: http://pastebin.com/tW1kntG3

The code in question lies around here:

```
#Define the variables
global currentLoc
currentLoc=0
```

(The part that is breaking the code, apparently, is line **37**.)

```
if call=="move":
    print("Move where?")
    print("")
    if currentLoc==0:
        print("Left: You cannot move left.")
        print("Right: " + locName[currentLoc+1])
    elif currentLoc>1:
        print("Left: " + locName[currentLoc-1])
        print("Right: " + locName[currentLoc+1])
    print("")
    print("Move left or right? Enter your choice.")
    direction = input("?: ")
    if direction=="left":
        print("Moved left.")
        if currentLoc>1:
            currentLoc = currentLoc-1
            pass
    elif direction=="right":
        currentLoc = currentLoc+1
        pass
pass
```

My error:

```
if currentLoc==0:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currentLoc' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Tried writing `global currentLoc` at the beginning of `displayMessage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a global *in the function*. Python determines name scope *per scope*. If you assign to a name in a function (or use it as an import target, or a `for` target, or an argument, etc.) then Python makes that name a local unless stated otherwise.

As such, using `global` at the global level is rather pointless, because Python already knows it is a global there.

Add your `global` statement into each of function that tries to alter the name:

```
def displayMessage(call):
    global currentLoc
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the one. Works like a charm; can't accept the answer for another 11 minutes but this is the one that worked. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

The `global` keyword introduces a global variable in a function's scope, it does not declare it as global for the whole program. You have to use `global var_name` in the function where you want to access the `var_name` variable.